# Auto complete commands with "windows like" options (starting with slash)

Tags: zsh, bash-completion, zsh-completion

I'm trying to write a custom auto-complete script for zsh (or bash) for a command that has options starting with a slash.

For instance: `MyCommand /foo=bar.txt /yolo=test /final=4`

I've been trying to use the zsh helper `_arguments` but it did not work:

```
#compdef MyCommand 

_MyCommand()
{
  local curcontext="$curcontext" state line
  typeset -A opt_args

  _arguments \
    '/foo=:foo:_files'
}

_MyCommand "$@"
```

But when I replace the `/` with `--` it works well.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `_regex_arguments` like this:

```
matchany=/$'[^\0]##\0'/
_regex_arguments _mycommand "$matchany" \( /$'/foo='/ ':option:option:(/foo=)' "$matchany" ':file:filename:_files' \| /$'/yolo='/ ':option:option:(/yolo=)' "$matchany" ':optarg:optarg:(test this)' \| /$'/final='/ ':option:option:(/final=)' /$'[0-9]##\0'/ ':number:number:' \) \#
_mycommand "$@"
```

You can read more about `_regex_arguments` here
http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Completion-Functions 
or here: https://github.com/vapniks/zsh-completions/blob/master/zsh-completions-howto.org

The important thing to note here is that there is no null char (\0) at the end of the pattern matches for the option names.

Comment: I've been late to the party, but a big thank to you :)